# Overleaf error messages when compiling with \begin{align*} and \end{align*} and using \bm{\varphi}

Tags: equations, errors, align, compilation-error, error-bars

I'm getting error messages in overleaf such as "Missing } inserted.", "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.", "Misplaced alignment tab character &.", "Misplaced alignment tab character &.", "Misplaced \omit.", "Misplaced \cr.", "Misplaced \noalign.", "Missing $ inserted." and "Missing \cr inserted."

It compiling when I use *equation* instead of *align* but doesnt otherwise. My code also compiles if I remove \bm{\varphi} and just write \varphi. It doesnt miss a { or } and no alignment is missplaced. I cant understand why it wouldn't compile and I really would like to use align instead of equation since it is much better looking. My code is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{chemist}
\newcommand{\rd}[1] {\ensuremath{\mathrm{d}#1}} %creates operator ds that makes it more clear that \frac{d}{dt} is an math operator 
\newcommand{\ham}{\mathcal{H}} %hamiltonian


\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
    \frac{\rd }{\rd t} \left( \left( \frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}_{t}}{\partial 
    \bm{y}_{0}} \right)^{T} J \left( \frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}_{t}}{\partial 
    \bm{y}_{0}} \right) \right) 
    &= \left(\frac{\rd}{\rd t} \frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}_{t} } {\partial \bm{y}_{0}}\right)^T J \left(\frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}_{t} } {\partial \bm{y}_{0}}\right) + \left(\frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}_{t} } {\partial \bm{y}_{0}} \right)^T J \left(\frac{\rd}{\rd t} \frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}_{t} } {\partial \bm{y}_{0}}\right)\\
    &=\left(\frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}_{t} } {\partial \bm{y}_{0}}\right)^T \nabla^2 \ham(\bm{\varphi}_t(\bm{y}_0)) J^T J \left(\frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}_{t} } {\partial \bm{y}_{0}}\right) + \left(\frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}_{t} } {\partial \bm{y}_{0}} \right)^T \nabla^2 \ham(\bm{\varphi}_t(\bm{y}_0)) \left( \frac{\partial \bm{\varphi}_{t} } {\partial \bm{y}_{0}}\right)\\
    &=0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

It seems that the code work if I put it into another blank overleaf document but doesn't work in my original document for some reason. **So to be clear if you copy this it will work but my code is approximately 2000 lines of code so might be something else or some smaller error that stack up?**

Comment: Did you load the package `bm` and `mathtools`? It compiles fine for me (but I have to guess the meaning of `\rd` as `\mathrm{d}`). Please consider adding a **minimum working example (MWE)**, i.e. from `\documentclass{article}` to `\end{document}` and can be tested to show the problem.

Comment: You'll need at least the `amsmath` and `bm` packages. As Teddy mentions, please always post full but minimal examples, not sniplets like this. Then we can see which class and packages you're loading and whether you're missing any.

Comment: Those are not complete examples. Please provide something that has any chance of even compiling on overleaf or elsewhere. We need something we can copy and test as is. Again here is no document class, there is no marking of document body. You need to provide something we can test that generates the error you get. Yes, it is annoying to create such an example, but it is an important debugging tool, both for you (because you learn how to identify the course of an error) and for us as we need something we can test.

Comment: I think my problem perhaps lies in some smaller problem that stack up. And thank you for your politeness. I just haven't used Stack Exchange TeX - LaTeX before. It is very useful for me to get to know the proper way of writing a question. If I had the reputation for it I would give you an upvote (and I know you shouldn't write stuff like thanks in here but you get it anyway since there isn't a proper way to show my appreciation and to not discourage you from correcting newbies in the future ;) ). Continue to correct me if I'm still unclear.

Comment: That example does not compile because `\ham` is not defined. BTW you can address a comment to a person if you use @name. You can send be a link to your overleaf project to daleif at math.au.dk, then I can copy it and have a look.

Comment: Just use `\newcommand{\rd}{\mathrm{d}}`; you're requiring an argument, but give none in `\frac{\rd}{\rd t}`

Comment: I tried this now @egreg but it still wouldn't compile. Though I'll use this in the future since it it more precise.

Comment: It seems that you have more `\left(` than `\right)`. The pairs should be matched in each group delimitted by `&` and \\ Consider to use `\right.` or fixed size parenthesis like`\biggl(`.

Comment: @ErikSahlin Sorry, but the code you posted shows no problem when I run LaTeX on it. If you don't post something that *does not* compile we can help in debugging it. Posting working code is not helpful, except for pointing out weaknesses.

Comment: @egreg Yes I know that is a part of what is weird. I have already stated this in the primary question. My thought was therefore either that the document had a structural problem which stacked up when left in the big overleaf document. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @Jhor When I counted the number of \right vs number of \left they where the same but If I dont manage to solve it I'll use \right. or \biggl( and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Otherwise download the Overleaf project as a zip and send it to me (daleif at math.au.dk), then I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @daleif thank you! I have shared the document with you. I wanted to try some stuff before I sent it to you

Comment: I've grabbed a copy. I'll have a look

Comment: Note that you are doing a lot of things wrong in this project and there are better methods for many of the constructions you use.

Comment: OK is there something in particular I should be aware of?

Comment: There is some package that is messing with `\bm{\varphi}`

Comment: A lot. I don't know how far you are in writing this, but I might suggest starting over with a blank preamble and only include what you actually need. For example framed theorems can be configured with a few lines in the preamble and then you can just use the `theorem` env. No need for `\fbox` and `minipage`. ``\\`` should never ever be used in the text. No blank lines before (and most often) after displayed math.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135374/discussion-between-daleif-and-erik-sahlin).

Comment: Thank you! Yes now I see that there's some problem with the combination of usepackages. Yes I also prefer a preamble to organize all the usepackages but in the template we got from the institution was a complete mess. I'll clean it up know and hopefully find which usepackage is not working properly. Big thank you!

Comment: This is also one of the reasons why I don't offer templates to the students at my department. You cannot make a template that fits every students needs and you'll just end up with a lot of stuff where half of it are never used.

Comment: I added a few more observations/recommendations to the chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having gotten access to the project in Overleaf, here are my observations.

The project cannot compile and the first error is

```
<inserted text> 
                }
l.439     \bm{\varphi}
                      _t (\bm{p}_0, \bm{q}_0) = (\bm{p}(t, \bm{p}_0, \bm{q}_...
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.439     \bm{\varphi}
                      _t (\bm{p}_0, \bm{q}_0) = (\bm{p}(t, \bm{p}_0, \bm{q}_..
```

That can be boiled down to

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{bm,mathtools}
\usepackage{chemist}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \bm{\varphi}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I don't think that `chemist` package is recommendable, one should probably use `mhchem` or `chemmacros` (I haven't looked into what `chemist` does other than it redefines `\varphi` and friends).

The next error was two labels in an `equation`. Lastly a missing comma in a `.bib` file. So in the end not too hard once I had access to the files.

The main take down here is: When Overleaf reports an error. Look at the first one. The rest can be accumulations that goes away once the first error is fixed.

Where the OP got the

```
Missing } inserted."...
```

error from I do not know, but it was not the first error listed when Overleaf compiled the project copy I had access to.